# Space-efficient reading of chars in canonical form

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

When using chars (lists of characters, thus atoms of length one) to represent text, we have the following options for writing them within terms:

- `"First,"` the double quoted list notation (6.3.7) is the most efficient one, requiring at least *n+2* characters.
  But it can only be read back if the Prolog flag [`double_quotes` is set to `chars`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36645725/772868).
- `['N',e,x,t,',']` comes the list notation with at least *2n+1* characters. While it is nice and relatively compact, it implies that also operators are used when writing other data since it is enabled with `ignore_ops(false)`, and this necessitates that the same operators will be present when reading, making it quite brittle.
- `'.'('L','.'(a,'.'(s,'.'(t,'.'(',',[])))))` the canonical notation which uses functional form also for lists requiring at least *7n+2* characters. That is a lot, but for interoperability (and that includes interoperability with the same system) it is best since it neither depends on the `double_quotes` flag nor the various operator declarations.

Writing chars in canonical notation can be done in [constant space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59835953/772868). But for reading, the situation is a bit more tricky. After all, a sequence starting with `'.'(a,` may also refer to a term `'.'(a,Further,b)`. So a naive reading will have to wait (and use space) until the entire list of chars is read in.  On the other hand, it seems to be a safe bet that `'.'(a,` will be a list constructor `'.'(a,Further)`. In other words,

How to read a term in canonical notation with constant auxiliary space for the reading of chars within?

In case it helps just consider terms `sampleterm/1`. So consider the reading of all such terms written in canonical form. And, if you like, formulate it as a DCG.

```
sampleterm([]).
sampleterm(a).
sampleterm(b).
sampleterm('.'(E,Es)) :- % the real list constructor 
   sampleterm(E),
   sampleterm(Es).
sampleterm('.'(E,F,G)) :- % no list constructor
   sampleterm(E),
   sampleterm(F),
   sampleterm(G).
```

If such space efficient reading is possible, then systems that support a compact internal representation of chars like Scryer and Trealla could even go a tiny step further.

Ah, lest I forget what I have tried: `read/1` indeed, but currently it was not ideal.

Comment: just for clarity: do strings in canonical notation have to be lists or can they be binary trees? I assume former but in your example `sampleterm/1` (the real list constructor) would accept trees as well.

Comment: @DuDa: Note that I avoid to use the word "string" as it is so ambiguous. Focus is on lists of characters and their efficient reading (within general reading which also may include  `'.'/3`).

Comment: Could you add an example to illustrate the perceived problem with `[nice, list, syntax]` and operators?

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie: See above, it's the option `ignore_ops(false)` which enables not only `[nice, list, syntax]` but also the current operators.

Comment: @false: Your `sampleterm` program throws an [instantiation_error in SWI](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/space-efficient-reading-of-chars-in-canonical-form.pl)

Comment: @gusbro:  This is about [tag:iso-prolog]-systems, SWI [no longer conforms](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/SWI7_and_ISO).

Answer (score 4):

The following straightforward code is based on Prolog streams.

It focuses on reading "real lists sampletrees" from repositionable streams.

For (1) non-repositionable streams and (2) handling `'.'/3` we fall back to `read/1`.

The main predicate is `read_sampleterm/1`:

```
read_sampleterm(Term) :-
    current_input(S),
    (  stream_property(S,reposition(true)),
       stream_property(S,position(P)),
       (  aux_read_sampleterm_1(Term0),
          get_char('.')                    % this is sloppy!
       -> true
       ;  set_stream_position(S,P),
          fail
       )
    -> Term = Term0
    ;  read(Term)                          % fallback
    ).
```

Note that above code is sloppy: at the end of the read, we need
to ensure that EOF or a character that does not combine with `'.'` follows.

The actual reading is done by the following auxiliary predicates:

```
aux_read_sampleterm_1(Term) :-
    get_char(Ch),
    aux_read_sampleterm_2(Ch,Term,0).      % use indexing

aux_read_sampleterm_2('\'',[X|Xs],N0) :-
    get_char('.'),
    get_char('\''),
    get_char('('),
    aux_read_sampleterm_1(X),
    get_char(','),
    N1 is N0 + 1,
    get_char(Ch),
    aux_read_sampleterm_2(Ch,Xs,N1).
aux_read_sampleterm_2('[',[],N) :-
    get_char(']'),
    eat_rparens(N).
aux_read_sampleterm_2(a,a,N) :-
    eat_rparens(N).
aux_read_sampleterm_2(b,b,N) :-
    eat_rparens(N).

eat_rparens(N) :-
    (  N > 0
    -> get_char(')'),
       N0 is N - 1,
       eat_rparens(N0)
    ;  true
    ).
```

To show some simple use cases we read from files:

```
read_sampleterm_from_file(File,Term) :-
    open(File,read,S,[type(text)]),
    current_input(S0),
    set_input(S),
    read_sampleterm(Term0),
    set_input(S0),
    close(S),
    Term = Term0.
```

Sample queries using GNU Prolog 1.5.0:

First, `sample1.txt`:

```
'.'(a,'.'(b,[])).
```

We get:

```
| ?- read_sampleterm_from_file('sample1.txt',T).

T = [a,b]

yes
```

Next, `sample2.txt`:

```
'.'(a,'.'(b,a)).
```

We get:

```
| ?- read_sampleterm_from_file('sample2.txt',T).

T = [a,b|a]

yes
```

`sample3.txt` is next:

```
'.'('.'(a,'.'(b,'.'(a,[]))),[]).
```

We get:

```
| ?- read_sampleterm_from_file('sample3.txt',T).

T = [[a,b,a]]

(1 ms) yes
```

Note that running above tests were run without the "fallback option".

Comment: No `peek_char/1`?

Comment: You only are able to read canonical char lists with constant space, when the term is exactly one such list of chars. But not even a list of chars can be read in efficiently. So this answers the question only for one very specific case only.

Comment: For clarification, consider `'.'('.'(a,'.'(b,'.'(c,[]))),[])` which is canonical for `["abc"]`

Comment: @false. How embarrassing... it didn't even occur to me that atom input streams could lack the `reposition(true)` property. In fact, in GNU Prolog they do...

Answer (score 1):

Lexer (`lexer.pl`):

```
:- module(lexer, []).

:- use_module(library(debug)).
:- use_module(library(dcgs)).
:- use_module(library(lists), [append/2, append/3, member/2]).


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Tokens.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

term(Ts) --> tokens(Ts).

% read_term(Ts) --> term(Ts0), end, !, { append(Ts0, [end], Ts) }.

read_term_([end]) --> end, !.
read_term_([T|Ts]) --> token(T), read_term_(Ts).

% Greedy.
tokens([T|Ts]) --> token(T), tokens(Ts).
tokens([]) --> [].

token(name(Cs)) --> name(Cs), !.
token(variable(Cs)) --> variable(Cs), !.
token(float_number(Cs)) --> float_number(Cs), !. % 3
token(integer(Cs)) --> integer(Cs), !. % 2
token(double_quoted_list(Cs)) --> double_quoted_list(Cs), !.
token(open) --> open, !.
token(open_ct) --> open_ct, !.
token(close) --> close_, !.
token(open_list) --> open_list, !.
token(close_list) --> close_list, !.
token(open_curly) --> open_curly, !.
token(close_curly) --> close_curly, !.
token(ht_sep) --> ht_sep, !.
token(comma) --> comma, !.

name(Cs) --> (layout_text_sequence '|' []), !, name_token(Cs).
variable(Cs) --> (layout_text_sequence '|' []), !, variable_token(Cs).
integer(Cs) --> (layout_text_sequence '|' []), !, integer_token(Cs).
float_number(Cs) --> (layout_text_sequence '|' []), !, float_number_token(Cs).
double_quoted_list(Cs) -->
    (layout_text_sequence '|' []), !, double_quoted_list_token(Cs).
open --> layout_text_sequence, open_token.
open_ct --> open_token.
close_ --> (layout_text_sequence '|' []), !, close_token.
open_list --> (layout_text_sequence '|' []), !, open_list_token.
close_list --> (layout_text_sequence '|' []), !, close_list_token.
open_curly --> (layout_text_sequence '|' []), !, open_curly_token.
close_curly --> (layout_text_sequence '|' []), !, close_curly_token.
ht_sep --> (layout_text_sequence '|' []), !, head_tail_separator_token.
comma --> (layout_text_sequence '|' []), !, comma_token.

end --> (layout_text_sequence '|' []), !, end_token.

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Layout text.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

layout_text_sequence --> layout_text, layout_texts.

% Greedy.
layout_texts --> layout_text, layout_texts.
layout_texts --> [].

layout_text --> layout_char(_), !.
layout_text --> comment, !.

comment --> single_line_comment, !.
comment --> bracketed_comment, !.

single_line_comment --> end_line_comment_char(_), comment_text, new_line_char(_).
% Greedy. The order is important.
% single_line_comment -->
%     end_line_comment_char(_), comment_text, new_line_char(_), !.
% single_line_comment -->
%     end_line_comment_char(_), comment_text, [_], !, { false }.
% single_line_comment --> end_line_comment_char(_), comment_text.

bracketed_comment --> comment_open, comment_text, comment_close.

comment_open --> comment_1_char, comment_2_char.
comment_close --> comment_2_char, comment_1_char.
comment_text --> chars(_).

comment_1_char --> "/".
comment_2_char --> "*".

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Names.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

name_token(Cs) --> letter_digit_token(Cs), !.
name_token(Cs) --> graphic_token(Cs), !.
name_token(Cs) --> quoted_token(Cs), !.
name_token(Cs) --> semicolon_token(Cs), !.
name_token(Cs) --> cut_token(Cs), !.

letter_digit_token([C|Cs]) --> small_letter_char(C), alphanumeric_chars(Cs).

graphic_token(_) --> ".", layout_char(_), !, { false }.
graphic_token(_) --> ".", end_line_comment_char(_), !, { false }.
graphic_token([C|Cs]) --> graphic_token_char(C), graphic_token_chars(Cs).

% Greedy.
graphic_token_chars([C|Cs]) --> graphic_token_char(C), graphic_token_chars(Cs).
graphic_token_chars([]) --> [].

graphic_token_char(C) --> graphic_char(C), !.
graphic_token_char(C) --> backslash_char(C), !.

quoted_token(Cs) -->
    single_quote_char(_),
    single_quoted_items(Cs),
    single_quote_char(_).

% Greedy.
single_quoted_items(Cs) -->
    single_quoted_item(Cs0),
    single_quoted_items(Cs1),
    { append(Cs0, Cs1, Cs) }.
single_quoted_items([]) --> [].

single_quoted_item([C]) --> single_quoted_character(C), !.
single_quoted_item([]) --> continuation_escape_sequence, !.

continuation_escape_sequence --> backslash_char(_), new_line_char(_).

semicolon_token([C]) --> semicolon_char(C).

cut_token([C]) --> cut_char(C).

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Quoted characters.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

single_quoted_character(C) --> non_quote_char(C), !.
single_quoted_character(C) --> single_quote_char(C), single_quote_char(C), !.
single_quoted_character(C) --> double_quote_char(C), !.
single_quoted_character(C) --> back_quote_char(C), !.

double_quoted_character(C) --> non_quote_char(C), !.
double_quoted_character(C) --> single_quote_char(C), !.
double_quoted_character(C) --> double_quote_char(C), double_quote_char(C), !.
double_quoted_character(C) --> back_quote_char(C), !.

back_quoted_character(C) --> non_quote_char(C), !.
back_quoted_character(C) --> single_quote_char(C), !.
back_quoted_character(C) --> double_quote_char(C), !.
back_quoted_character(C) --> back_quote_char(C), back_quote_char(C), !.

non_quote_char(C) --> graphic_char(C), !.
non_quote_char(C) --> alphanumeric_char(C), !.
non_quote_char(C) --> solo_char(C), !.
non_quote_char(C) --> space_char(C), !.
non_quote_char(C) --> meta_escape_sequence(C), !.
non_quote_char(C) --> control_escape_sequence(C), !.
non_quote_char(C) --> octal_escape_sequence(C), !.
non_quote_char(C) --> hexadecimal_escape_sequence(C), !.

meta_escape_sequence(C) --> backslash_char(_), meta_char(C0),
    { member(C0-C, [('\\')-('\\'), ''''-'''', '"'-'"', '`'-'`']), ! }.

control_escape_sequence(C) --> backslash_char(_), symbolic_control_char(C0),
    {   member(
            C0-C,
            [
                'a'-'\a',
                'b'-'\b',
                'r'-'\r',
                'f'-'\f',
                't'-'\t',
                'n'-'\n',
                'v'-'\v'
            ]
        ), !
    }.

symbolic_control_char(C) --> symbolic_alert_char(C), !.
symbolic_control_char(C) --> symbolic_backspace_char(C), !.
symbolic_control_char(C) --> symbolic_carriage_return_char(C), !.
symbolic_control_char(C) --> symbolic_form_feed_char(C), !.
symbolic_control_char(C) --> symbolic_horizontal_tab_char(C), !.
symbolic_control_char(C) --> symbolic_new_line_char(C), !.
symbolic_control_char(C) --> symbolic_vertical_tab_char(C), !.

symbolic_alert_char('a') --> "a".
symbolic_backspace_char('b') --> "b".
symbolic_carriage_return_char('r') --> "r".
symbolic_form_feed_char('f') --> "f".
symbolic_horizontal_tab_char('t') --> "t".
symbolic_new_line_char('n') --> "n".
symbolic_vertical_tab_char('v') --> "v".

octal_escape_sequence(C) -->
    backslash_char(_),
    octal_digit_char(C0),
    octal_digit_chars(Cs),
    backslash_char(_),
    {   number_chars(N, ['0', 'o', C0|Cs]),
        char_code(C, N)
    }.

hexadecimal_escape_sequence(C) -->
    backslash_char(_),
    symbolic_hexadecimal_char(C0),
    hexadecimal_digit_char(C1),
    hexadecimal_digit_chars(Cs),
    backslash_char(_),
    {   number_chars(N, ['0', C0, C1|Cs]),
        char_code(C, N)
    }.

symbolic_hexadecimal_char('x') --> "x".

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Variables.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

variable_token(Cs) --> named_variable(Cs), !. % 1
variable_token(Cs) --> anonymous_variable(Cs), !. % 0

anonymous_variable([C]) --> variable_indicator_char(C).

named_variable([C0, C1|Cs]) -->
    variable_indicator_char(C0), !,
    alphanumeric_char(C1),
    alphanumeric_chars(Cs).
named_variable([C|Cs]) -->
    capital_letter_char(C), !,
    alphanumeric_chars(Cs).

variable_indicator_char(C) --> underscore_char(C).

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Integer numbers.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

integer_token(Cs) --> character_code_constant(Cs), !.
integer_token(Cs) --> binary_constant(Cs), !.
integer_token(Cs) --> octal_constant(Cs), !.
integer_token(Cs) --> hexadecimal_constant(Cs), !.
integer_token(Cs) --> integer_constant(Cs), !.

integer_constant([C|Cs]) --> decimal_digit_char(C), decimal_digit_chars(Cs).

character_code_constant(['0', C0, C]) -->
    "0", single_quote_char(C0), single_quoted_character(C).

binary_constant(Cs) -->
    binary_constant_indicator(Cs0),
    binary_digit_char(C),
    binary_digit_chars(Cs1),
    { append(Cs0, [C|Cs1], Cs) }.

binary_constant_indicator("0b") --> "0b".

octal_constant(Cs) -->
    octal_constant_indicator(Cs0),
    octal_digit_char(C),
    octal_digit_chars(Cs1),
    { append(Cs0, [C|Cs1], Cs) }.

octal_constant_indicator("0o") --> "0o".

hexadecimal_constant(Cs) -->
    hexadecimal_constant_indicator(Cs0),
    hexadecimal_digit_char(C),
    hexadecimal_digit_chars(Cs1),
    { append(Cs0, [C|Cs1], Cs) }.

hexadecimal_constant_indicator("0x") --> "0x".

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Floating point numbers.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

float_number_token(Cs) -->
    integer_constant(Cs0),
    fraction(Cs1),
    exponent(Cs2),
    { append([Cs0, Cs1, Cs2], Cs) }.

fraction([C0, C1|Cs]) -->
    decimal_point_char(C0),
    decimal_digit_char(C1),
    decimal_digit_chars(Cs).

% Greedy.
exponent([C|Cs]) --> exponent_char(C), sign(Cs0), integer_constant(Cs1), !,
    { append(Cs0, Cs1, Cs) }.
exponent([]) --> [].

% Greedy.
sign([C]) --> negative_sign_char(C), !.
sign([C]) --> positive_sign_char(C), !.
sign([]) --> [].

positive_sign_char('+') --> "+".
negative_sign_char('-') --> "-".
decimal_point_char('.') --> ".".
exponent_char(C) --> [C], { member(C, "eE"), ! }.

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Double quoted lists.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

double_quoted_string(Cs) -->
    double_quote_char(_),
    double_quoted_item(Cs0),
    double_quoted_char(_),
    append(["""", Cs0, """"], Cs).

% Greedy.
double_quoted_items(Cs) -->
    double_quoted_item(Cs0), double_quoted_items(Cs1),
    { append(Cs0, Cs1, Cs) }.
double_quoted_items([]) --> [].

double_quoted_item([C]) --> double_quoted_character(C), !.
double_quoted_item([]) --> continuation_escape_sequence, !.

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Double quoted lists.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

double_quoted_list_token(Cs) -->
    double_quote_char(C),
    double_quoted_items(Cs),
    double_quote_char(C).

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Back quoted strings.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

back_quoted_string -->
    back_quote_char,
    back_quoted_items,
    back_quoted_char.

% Greedy.
back_quoted_items --> back_quoted_item, back_quoted_items.
back_quoted_items --> [].

back_quoted_item --> back_quoted_character, !.
back_quoted_item --> continuation_escape_sequence, !.

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Other tokens.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

open_token --> open_char(_).
close_token --> close_char(_).
open_list_token --> open_list_char(_).
close_list_token --> close_list_char(_).
open_curly_token --> open_curly_char(_).
close_curly_token --> close_curly_char(_).
head_tail_separator_token --> head_tail_separator_char(_).
comma_token --> comma_char(_).

% The order is important.
% Greedy. TODO: Find better.
end_token, [C] --> end_char, layout_char(C), !.
end_token, "%" --> end_char, end_line_comment_char(_), !.
end_token --> end_char, [_], !, { false }.
end_token --> end_char.

end_char --> ".".

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Processor character set.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

% Not greedy.
chars([]) --> [].
chars([C|Cs]) --> char(C), chars(Cs).

char(C) --> graphic_char(C), !.
char(C) --> alphanumeric_char(C), !.
char(C) --> solo_char(C), !.
char(C) --> layout_char(C), !.
char(C) --> meta_char(C), !.
char(C) --> [C], { write('Accepting: \''), write(C), write(''''), nl }.

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Graphic characters.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

graphic_char(C) --> [C], { member(C, "#$&*+-./:<=>?@^~"), ! }.

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Alphanumeric characters.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

% Greedy.
alphanumeric_chars([C|Cs]) -->
    alphanumeric_char(C),
    alphanumeric_chars(Cs).
alphanumeric_chars([]) --> [].

alphanumeric_char(C) --> alpha_char(C), !.
alphanumeric_char(C) --> decimal_digit_char(C), !.

alpha_char(C) --> underscore_char(C), !.
alpha_char(C) --> letter_char(C), !.

letter_char(C) --> capital_letter_char(C), !.
letter_char(C) --> small_letter_char(C), !.

% Greedy.
decimal_digit_chars([C|Cs]) --> decimal_digit_char(C), decimal_digit_chars(Cs).
decimal_digit_chars([]) --> [].
% Greedy.
binary_digit_chars([C|Cs]) --> binary_digit_char(C), binary_digit_chars(Cs).
binary_digit_chars([]) --> [].
% Greedy.
octal_digit_chars([C|Cs]) --> octal_digit_char(C), octal_digit_chars(Cs).
octal_digit_chars([]) --> [].
% Greedy.
hexadecimal_digit_chars([C|Cs]) -->
    hexadecimal_digit_char(C), hexadecimal_digit_chars(Cs).
hexadecimal_digit_chars([]) --> [].

small_letter_char(C) --> [C], { member(C, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), ! }.
capital_letter_char(C) --> [C], { member(C, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), ! }.
decimal_digit_char(C) --> [C], { member(C, "0123456789"), ! }.
binary_digit_char(C) --> [C], { member(C, "01"), ! }.
octal_digit_char(C) --> [C], { member(C, "01234567"), ! }.
hexadecimal_digit_char(C) --> [C], { member(C, "0123456789AaBbCcDdEeFf"), ! }.
underscore_char('_') --> "_".

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Solo characters.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

solo_char(C) --> cut_char(C), !.
solo_char(C) --> open_char(C), !.
solo_char(C) --> close_char(C), !.
solo_char(C) --> comma_char(C), !.
solo_char(C) --> semicolon_char(C), !.
solo_char(C) --> open_list_char(C), !.
solo_char(C) --> close_list_char(C), !.
solo_char(C) --> open_curly_char(C), !.
solo_char(C) --> close_curly_char(C), !.
solo_char(C) --> head_tail_separator_char(C), !.
solo_char(C) --> end_line_comment_char(C), !.

cut_char('!') --> "!".
open_char('(') --> "(".
close_char(')') --> ")".
comma_char((',')) --> ",".
semicolon_char(';') --> ";".
open_list_char('[') --> "[".
close_list_char(']') --> "]".
open_curly_char('{') --> "{".
close_curly_char('}') --> "}".
head_tail_separator_char('|') --> "|".
end_line_comment_char('%') --> "%".

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Layout characters.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

layout_char(C) --> space_char(C), !.
layout_char(C) --> horizontal_tab_char(C), !.
layout_char(C) --> new_line_char(C), !.

space_char(' ') --> " ".
horizontal_tab_char('\t') --> "\t".
new_line_char('\n') --> "\n".

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Meta characters.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

meta_char(C) --> backslash_char(C), !.
meta_char(C) --> single_quote_char(C), !.
meta_char(C) --> double_quote_char(C), !.
meta_char(C) --> back_quote_char(C), !.

backslash_char('\\') --> "\\".
single_quote_char('''') --> "'".
double_quote_char('"') --> """".
back_quote_char('`') --> "`".
```

Parser (`parser.pl`):

```
:- module(parser, []).

:- use_module(library(debug)).
:- use_module(library(dcgs)).
:- use_module(library(error)).
:- use_module(library(format)).
:- use_module(library(lists)).


state(S), [S] --> [S].
state(S0, S), [S] --> [S0].

print --> state(s(Ts, Ss, CsVs)), { format("~q ~q ~q\n", [Ts, Ss, CsVs]) }.
print(Cs) -->
    state(s(Ts, Ss, CsVs)),
    { format("~s ~q ~q ~q\n", [Cs, Ts, Ss, CsVs]) }.


lookahead(T) --> state(s([T|_], _, _)).

shift --> state(s([name(Cs)|Ts], Ss, CsVs), s(Ts, [term(atom,A)|Ss], CsVs)),
    { atom_chars(A, Cs) }.
shift -->
    state(
        s([open_list,close_list|Ts], Ss, CsVs),
        s(Ts, [term(atom,[])|Ss], CsVs)
    ).
shift -->
    state(
        s([open_curly,close_curly|Ts], Ss, CsVs),
        s(Ts, [term(atom,{})|Ss], CsVs)
    ).
shift -->
    state(s([variable(Cs)|Ts], Ss, CsVs0), s(Ts, [term(variable,V)|Ss], CsVs)),
    { variable(Cs, CsVs0, V, CsVs) }.
shift -->
    state(
        s([integer(Cs)|Ts], [term(atom,-)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [term(integer,N)|Ss], CsVs)
    ), !,
    { number_chars(N, [-|Cs]) }.
shift -->
    state(
        s([float_number(Cs)|Ts], [term(atom,-)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [term(float,N)|Ss], CsVs)
    ), !,
    { number_chars(N, [-|Cs]) }.
shift -->
    state(
        s([integer(Cs)|Ts], Ss, CsVs),
        s(Ts, [term(integer,N)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    { number_chars(N, Cs) }.
shift -->
    state(
        s([float_number(Cs)|Ts], Ss, CsVs),
        s(Ts, [term(float,N)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    { number_chars(N, Cs) }.
shift -->
    state(
        s([open_ct|Ts], [term(atom,A)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [compound(A,As,As)|Ss], CsVs)
    ), !.
shift --> state(s([open|Ts], Ss, CsVs), s(Ts, [open|Ss], CsVs)).
shift --> state(s([open_ct|Ts], Ss, CsVs), s(Ts, [open_ct|Ss], CsVs)).
% /*
shift -->
    state(
        s([close|Ts], [term(_,T),dot(0,Cs0)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [term(chars, Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    { append(Cs0, T, Cs) }.
shift -->
    state(
        s([close|Ts], [term(_,T),dot(N0,Cs0)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [dot(N,Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    { succ(N, N0), append(Cs0, T, Cs) }.
shift -->
    state(
        s([close|Ts], [dot(0,Cs)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [term(chars,Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ).
shift -->
    state(
        s([close|Ts], [dot(N0,Cs)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [dot(N,Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    { succ(N, N0) }.
% */
shift -->
    state(
        s([close|Ts], [term(_,T0),compound(A,As,[T0])|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [term(compound,T)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    { T =.. [A|As] }.
shift -->
    state(
        s([close|Ts], [term(_,T),open|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [term(compound,T)|Ss], CsVs)
    ).
shift -->
    state(
        s([close|Ts], [term(_,T),open_ct|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [term(compound,T)|Ss], CsVs)
    ).
% /*
shift -->
    state(
        % s([comma|Ts], [term(atom,A),compound('.',As,As))|Ss], CsVs),
        s([comma|Ts], [term(atom,A),compound('.',As,_)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [dot(0,[A])|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    % { acyclic_term(As), atom_length(A, 1) },
    { var(As), atom_length(A, 1) },
    reduce, !.
shift -->
    state(
        s([comma|Ts], [term(_,T),dot(0,[A])|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [compound('.',[A,T|As],As)|Ss], CsVs)
    ).
shift -->
    state(
        s([comma|Ts], [term(_,T),dot(N0,Cs0)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [compound('.',[A,T|As],As),dot(N,Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    { succ(N, N0), append(Cs, [A], Cs0) }.
shift -->
    state(
        s([comma|Ts], [dot(0,[A|Cs])|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [compound('.',[A,Cs|As],As)|Ss], CsVs)
    ).
shift -->
    state(
        s([comma|Ts], [dot(N0,Cs0)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [compound('.',[A,Cs1|As],As),dot(N,Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    {   succ(N, N0),
        length(Cs, N0),
        append(Cs, [A|Cs1], Cs0)
    }.
% */
shift -->
    state(
        s([comma|Ts], [term(_,T),compound(A,As0,[T|As])|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [compound(A,As0,As)|Ss], CsVs)
    ).

reduce -->
    state(
        s(Ts, [dot(0,[A]),dot(N0,Cs0)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [dot(N,Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    { succ(N0, N), append(Cs0, [A], Cs) }, !.
reduce --> [].



read_term_ -->
    % print,
    lookahead(end), !,
    accept.
read_term_ -->
    shift, !,
    read_term_.

accept --> state(s([end], [term(_,_)], _)), !.
accept -->
    print("End"), { false }.
    % { throw(error(reduction(imcomplete), read_term//0)) }.

variable("_", CsVs, _, CsVs) :- !.
variable(Cs, CsVs, V, CsVs) :-
    member(Cs-V, CsVs), !.
variable(Cs, CsVs, V, [Cs-V|CsVs]).

succ(X, S) :-
    can_be(not_less_than_zero,X),
    can_be(not_less_than_zero,S),
    ( nonvar(X) -> S is X+1 ; X is S-1, X >= 0 ).

sml(S, M, Xs0, Xs) :-
    '$skip_max_list'(S, M, Xs0, Xs).
```

The initialization file `init.pl`:

```
:- use_module(library(debug)).
:- use_module(library(charsio)).
:- use_module(library(dcgs)).
:- use_module(library(dif)).
:- use_module(library(lists)).
:- use_module(library(iso_ext)).
:- use_module(library(pairs)).
:- use_module(library(pio)).
:- use_module(library(format)).
:- use_module(lexer).
:- use_module(parser).

parse(Cs, Ts, Ss0, S) :-
    phrase(lexer:read_term_(Ts), Cs),
    Ss0 = [s(Ts, [], [])|_],
    phrase(parser:read_term_, Ss0, [S]).

sample(a) --> [a].
sample([]) --> [[]].
sample('.'(E)) --> ['.'], sample(E).
sample('.'(E,Es)) --> ['.'], sample(E), sample(Es).
sample('.'(E,F,G)) --> ['.'], sample(E), sample(F), sample(G).
sample('.'(E,F,G,H)) --> ['.'], sample(E), sample(F), sample(G), sample(H).

generate(T, N) :-
    length(Cs, N),
    phrase(sample(T), Cs).

test :-
    once(generate('.'(a,'.'(a,'.'(a,'.'(a,[]))),a), _)),
    % N = 72849,
    call_nth(user:generate(T, _), N),
    ( N mod 2^10 =:= 0, writeq(N), nl, false ; true ),
    % T = '.'('.'(a,[]),[]),
    % T = '.'('.'(aa,'.'(b,'.'(c,[]))),[]),
    write_term_to_chars(T, [quoted(true),ignore_ops(true)], Cs0),
    append(Cs0, ".", Cs),
    (   parse(Cs, _, _, _) ->
        parse(Cs, Ts, Ss, S),
        S = s(_,[term(_,T0)],_),
        T0 \== T,
        format("N = ~q,\nCs = ~q,\nTs = ~q,\nSs = ~q,\nS = ~q.\n\n", [N,Cs,Ts,Ss,S])
    ;   format("N = ~q,\nCs = ~q,\nT = ~q.\n\n", [N,Cs,T])
    ),
    halt.
test :-
    halt.

dif(V, S0, V) :-
    dif(V, S0).

ns_ --> "(".
ns_ --> ")".
ns_ --> "'.'".
ns_ --> "a".

ns --> [].
ns --> ns_, ns.

nonsense(Cs) :-
    length(Cs, _),
    [C0|Cs0] = Cs,
    foldl(dif, Cs0, C0, _),
    phrase(ns, Cs).

nonsense :-
    call_nth(nonsense(Cs0), N),
    ( N mod 2^10 =:= 0, writeq(N), nl, false ; true ),
    append(Cs0, ".", Cs),
    (   parse(Cs, Ts, Ss, S),
        \+ catch(read_from_chars(Cs, _), error(syntax_error(_),_), false),
        format("N = ~q,\nCs = ~q,\nTs = ~q,\nSs = ~q,\nS = ~q.\n\n", [N,Cs,Ts,Ss,S])
    ;   catch(read_from_chars(Cs, T), error(syntax_error(_),_), false),
        \+ parse(Cs, Ts, Ss, S),
        \+ member(N, [161,749,822,3819]),
        format("N = ~q,\nCs = ~q,\nT = ~q.\n\n", [N,Cs,T])
    ),
    halt.
nonsense :-
    halt.
```

Using Scryer Prolog with `scryer-prolog init -g test`. It can also be queried like `?- parse("'.'(a,[]).", Ts, Ss, S).`. By uncommenting `print//0` in `read_term_//0` in `parser.pl` (or using `state(S0, S), [S] --> [S0,S].`), the transition can be visualized.

In the step by step, `dot/2` and `term(chars,_)` use a compact internal representation.

Some information is lost in this implementation (can't be seeing but present), example when parsing `'.'('.'(a,[]),[]).`:

```
...
[close,comma,open_list,close_list,close,end] [term(atom,[]),dot(0,"a"),compound('.',A,A)] []
[comma,open_list,close_list,close,end] [term(chars,"a"),compound('.',A,A)] []
[open_list,close_list,close,end] [compound('.',["a"|A],A)] [] % "a" still compactly stored.
...
```

Some grammar rules of `shift//0` can be commented to fall back to the unoptimized parser.

The space complexity is `O(ln N)` where `N` is the size of the list of characters (not token nor input).

In the worst case (`[]`, `'.'(a,a([]))`, `'.'(a,a('.'(a,a([]))))`, etc), the space complexity is `O(N ln N)` where `N` is the number of tokens.

In the best case (`[]`, `'.'(a,[])`, `'.'(a,'.'(a,[]))`, etc), the space complexity is `O(ln N)` where `N` is the number of tokens.

Comment: The enumeration in `sample/2` is inefficient, as the very same terms are generated over and over again. Instead use a difference for the bound which assures that each answer/solution is unique.

Comment: minor: use [`succ/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#succ)

Comment: I will try to make `sample/2` efficient.

Comment: Scryer doesn't have `succ/2`.

Comment: `succ(X, S) :- can_be(not_less_than_zero,X), can_be(not_less_than_zero,S), ( nonvar(X) -> S is X+1 ; X is S-1, X >= 0 ).`

Answer (score 1):

The order is important because of cut and regular compound term.

```
shift --> % 0
    state(
        s([close|Ts], [term(_,T),dot(0,Cs0)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [term(chars, Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    { append(Cs0, T, Cs) }.
shift --> % 1
    state(
        s([close|Ts], [term(_,T),dot(N0,Cs0)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [dot(N,Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    { succ(N, N0), append(Cs0, T, Cs) }.
shift --> % 2
    state(
        s([close|Ts], [dot(0,Cs)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [term(chars,Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ).
shift --> % 3
    state(
        s([close|Ts], [dot(N0,Cs)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [dot(N,Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    { succ(N, N0) }.
shift --> % 4
    state(
        % s([comma|Ts], [term(atom,A),compound('.',As,As))|Ss], CsVs),
        s([comma|Ts], [term(atom,A),compound('.',As,_)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [dot(0,[A])|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    % { acyclic_term(As), atom_length(A, 1) },
    { var(As), atom_length(A, 1) },
    reduce, !.
shift --> % 5
    state(
        s([comma|Ts], [term(_,T),dot(0,[A])|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [compound('.',[A,T|As],As)|Ss], CsVs)
    ).
shift --> % 6
    state(
        s([comma|Ts], [term(_,T),dot(N0,Cs0)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [compound('.',[A,T|As],As),dot(N,Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    { succ(N, N0), append(Cs, [A], Cs0) }.
shift --> % 7
    state(
        s([comma|Ts], [dot(0,[A|Cs])|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [compound('.',[A,Cs|As],As)|Ss], CsVs)
    ).
shift --> % 8
    state(
        s([comma|Ts], [dot(N0,Cs0)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [compound('.',[A,Cs1|As],As),dot(N,Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    {   succ(N, N0),
        length(Cs, N0),
        append(Cs, [A|Cs1], Cs0)
    }.

reduce -->
    state(
        s(Ts, [dot(0,[A]),dot(N0,Cs0)|Ss], CsVs),
        s(Ts, [dot(N,Cs)|Ss], CsVs)
    ),
    { succ(N0, N), append(Cs0, [A], Cs) }, !.
reduce --> [].

succ(X, S) :-
    can_be(not_less_than_zero,X),
    can_be(not_less_than_zero,S),
    ( nonvar(X) -> S is X+1 ; X is S-1, X >= 0 ).
```

This is the part added to the parser. It has been simplified a bit.

This parser is optimistic and assumes a list of characters is to be parsed when it sees `'.'(` followed by a character.

For an input like `'.'(a,'.'(a,b,b),b)`, the parser will first build `"aa"` (`chars`) then undo it step by step to build the term. The first undo builds `'.'(a,b,b)` but the parser is still optimistic since `[a|'.'(a,b,b)]` could be built so `"a"` is a `chars`. But an undo is done again to build `'.'(a,'.'(a,b,b),b)`.

There is also the case where the input is `'.'(a,'.'(b,[]),c)`, the parse builds `"ab"` then needs to undo to build `'.'(a,"b",c)`. The `chars` `"ab"` is split with `"b"` being a `chars`.

An input more complicated is like `'.'(a,'.'(b,'.'(c,[]),d))`, the parser builds "abc", then undo by splitting as `"a"`, `'.'(b` and `"c"`. Now the parser builds `'.'(b,"c",d)` with `"c"` being a `chars` and `"a"` also being a `chars`. Finally, it finishes parsing to `[a|'.'(b,"c",d)]` with `[a|` and `"c"` being `chars`.

It starts with `% 4`, if the compound term with atom `'.'` doesn't have any argument and the atom is a character then assumes a list of characters will be parsed and store the character efficiently (`dot(0,[A])`). Then `reduce//0` the `dot`s, on a procedural language the stack could be inspected further instead of using `reduce` like here.

A finalized `chars` is built after `% 0` or `% 2`.

The splitting is done with `% 6`, `% 7` and `% 8`.

The shift `% 5` handles `'.'(a,T,`, it turns `"a"` into that.

The shift `% 3` confirms how much of a `chars` is actually a `chars`. In `dot(N, Cs)`, `N` may not be a `chars` but the tail is.

The shift `% 1` inserts the tails and confirms by decreasing `N0`.

Comment: Clearly a step ahead! I more and more believe that the cleanest way would be to solve this in the tokenizer.

Comment: A [lexerless parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scannerless_parsing)? When the parser sees `'.'(a,'.'(a,`, it isn't certain that the result will be a `chars` since `b,b),b)` can follow. So here, after 8 tokens the parser still can't decide.

Comment: The tokenizer could count that number of missing closing round brackets. Thus it can detect a canonical string just during parsing, and for more complex cases it could produce one (kind of) list prefix as a token to be left for the actual parser. Somewhat similar to the way how [constant space writing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59835953/772868) is done.

Comment: Possible but it will be like `dot(N,Cs)` since `N+1` is the number of parentheses needed to confirm the first part.

Comment: Right, so strictly speaking, it's not about constant space but rather logarithmic, except that a significant growth is not observable to us mortals in this tiny finite world.